# Аналог LIKE (поиск подстроки) в LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, linq

Как переделать данный запрос, чтобы было что-то вроде

`WHERE movie.Title LIKE "searchString"`

То есть поиск подстроки, а не целой строки.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchString)
    {
        IEnumerable<Movie> MovieQuery =
            from movie in db.Movie
            where movie.Title == searchString
            select movie;

        return View(MovieQuery);
    }
```

Comment: `Title.Contains(searchString)`

Comment: Оу, так просто... Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как уже написали, подойдет `Title.Contains(searchString)`, но если проверять надо более сложное вхождение, то лучше так:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchString)
{
    IEnumerable<Movie> MovieQuery =
        from movie in db.Movie
        where SqlMethods.Like(movie.Title, "%Номер:%"+searchString+"%")
        select movie;

    return View(MovieQuery);
}
```

В примере проверяется два вхождения, сначала `"Номер:"`, а после него через любое количество символов должно быть значение переменной `searchString`.

Comment: а что такое `%Номер:%` ?

Comment: Для примера, суть в том что здесь можно использовать более сложную маску.